# GCC warning declaration of ‘x’ shadows a member of Class y

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda

I have a lambda declared in a member function of a class called `KoalaClass`.
The compiler is warning me that declaration of ‘vertices_’ shadows a member of ‘KoalaClass’. `vertices_` is a member of a class called `KoalaClass`.

```
std::find_if(vertices_.begin(), vertices_.end(), [&sourceName, this](koalaGraph::PVertex const& vertices_) {return sourceName == vertices_->info.name;}
```

Could somebody explain why this is happening and if I have coded the lambda incorrectly coded?

Comment: You likely want to name the parameter of your lambda as "vertex" not "vertices_".

Comment: Your code will work, but it's generally not a good idea to have a collection and an element of that collection named the same thing, so I would suggest listening to the warning and changing the inner variable.